# REST API design for querying the latest version of an APP

Tags: rest

I am designing a REST　API　that querys the latest version of an APP and returns the download url.

The problems I am encountering are that:

1. GET vs POST

I have json parameter that varies and its very long, so I can not put it in the url, meaning that i can't use GET request. Using POST method violates the REST API semantics, which is not what i want to do.

2. Good API design

for example: `/xxxx/apps/latestversion/package` for querying the latest version of an APP. Is this good practice?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand why a request for the latest version requires JSON data. Please give more details about the REST resource, what request data is required, and why it is needed.

Comment: A GET _can_ contain a Request Body, but servers are not expected to consider it. You could make an exception here. Or --just thinking-- you could shift the body to path params. But frankly speaking, what params could that might be? One wants the latest package of an app, beside the OS/architecture, what could be path params, I see no need of additional information.

Comment: @LutzHorn As I said, because lots of parameters and they could be very long

Comment: Show us the details.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API do differ GET from POST i.e GET to get data without changing state of objects and POST for changing state and such

but the http scheme for GET and POST is that GET use it's query params at the url, because there is a length limit and your json payload is big as you mention you don't have other option than using POST

your url scheme looks fine, it doesn't matter so much anyway..

Comment: If the request uses TLS, query parameters are not less secure than the request body.

Comment: @LutzHorn you are basically right... changed my answer